# url rewrite not working in apache?

Tags: php, .htaccess

hi im working with PHP application. Now i wanted to implement the URL rewrite concept for SEO friendly
My Current URL is `domain.com?category-view.php?manufacturer=Apple`

i wanted the above URL as

```
domain.com/category-view/manufacturer/apple (or)

domain.com/category-view/apple
```

I have created the .htaccess file and put this code for rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]{4,60})$ category-view.php?manufacturer=$1
```

But its not working up. help me  to fix this

Comment: At least the dash should be escaped in the character set definition `[A-Za-z0-9_\-]`

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel You're right. Some regex implementation do require that dash and backslash are escaped inside []. This one doesn't.

Comment: @lkke - in the sense im getting like "domain.com?category-view.php?manufacturer=Apple" instead of what i want "domain.com/category-view/manufacturer/apple "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load mod_rewrite

> 1. Before you begin this, please make sure you make a backup copy of the original file in case you make a mistake, this way you can always go back to the original configuration - always backup before you begin doing something like this.)
> 2. Find the httpd.conf file (usually you will find it in a folder called conf, config or something along those lines. In Fedora you can find it at /etc/httpd/ directory.)
> 3. Inside the httpd.conf file find and uncomment the line LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so (remove the pound '#' sign from in front of the line - the # sign is for comments, by removing the # sign, you are uncommenting the line)
> 4. Also find the line ClearModuleList is uncommented then find and make sure that the line AddModule mod_rewrite.c is not commented out. (I didnt find these in Fedora, yet my mod_rewrite works great)
> 5. After you have made the changes and saved them, restart your httpd (apache) server for the changes to take affect. The easiest way to do this is to go to the shell command and type: /etc/init.d/httpd restart (this works for Fedora, might be different for other distributions!)
> 6. Done

from http://www.wallpaperama.com/disp-post10.html

see also http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category-view/([A-Za-z0-9_\-]{4,60})$ category-view.php?manufacturer=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html when you use a `RewriteRule` in a .htaccess file you need to specify the base url using `RewriteBase` or it substitutes the *filesystem path* instead. So, try adding this to your .htasccess file:

```
RewriteBase ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before "RewriteEngine On"

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see that mod_rewrite is enabled on your installation? You can quickly check by putting `<?php phpinfo() ?>` in your file. Do a find for 'mod_rewrite'.

Comment: yes i did check 'mod_rewrite' in loaded module  its already there